# Ajax back button jquery - Need full example step by step

Tags: hash, button, jquery, history, back

I need help supporting back button with jquery ajax.load method.

I have tried a couple of plugins but i cant get any of them to work.

I am loading my content like this:

```
 $('.pagination a').click(function(){        
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            ajaxLoad(url,null,'.container');   
            return false;
        });
```

Note: ajaxLoad function executes the jquery load method.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is not very clear. Maybe you could try to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well a have some kind of news portal and the news are paginated (using ajax to load the next page like i showed in the code (the page links are generated from php.
I need to allow the back button so a user browsing the news can go back to previous page using the browser back button.

Answer (score 0):

for back button in ajax you can save page status by Anchor where in each load you change the url  anchor (as called page bookmarks)
Eg:

```
www.yoursite.com/page.aspx
//Load Article number 1
www.yoursite.com/page.aspx#art1
//Load Article number 2
www.yoursite.com/page.aspx#art2
```

you can change it using window.location

you will notice this in Gmail when you look at url
read more about anchors with ajax

Comment: yes i kwow the theory but i am having troubles put it in practice.